# No module named "PyQt5" found when using pyinstaller to create exe

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create an .exe from my .py file. I'm using Pycharm with Python 3.7, PyQt5, and on windows. Every time I run the command, it seems to work and produces the directory/file, but when I run the file, it immediately crashes. When I ran it with CMD, it says "no module found named PyQt5".

I've looked through just about everything, and most people's solutions just don't seem to work with mine for some reason. I've tried adding PyQt5 to hiddenImports, I've tried adding the bin folder to PyQt from the venv to the path. I've also tried adding pyqt5.uic because someone said that might work.

Here's my command I'm running right now:

```
pyinstaller -y -p C:\Users\Velox\Downloads\Project\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin --hidden-import PyQt5 "app.py"
```

Here's the exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "app.py", line 6, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "PyQt5"
[7112] Failed to execute script app
```

Comment: Have you tried using a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)? you don't need to do anything to use PyQt if you use env and the latest version of pyinstaller.

Comment: @M.R. I am using conda environment and pyinstaller3.4 and getting same error on osx Mojave

Comment: Install a virtualenv and install both Pyinstaller and PyQt5 on it (in your main Python environment). Next just freeze your app with `pyinstaller script.py`.